# PDE Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pde

I'm newbie with Mathematica, so probably my problem is very easy to be solved. 
I want to solve a PDE:

[image: Click to check the script]

The first problem is that the program is not substituting the values inside w[x,y] and its second derivatives, to use them as boundary conditions. 
It tells me that `Tag Equal in ((w1^(2,0))[x,y]==0)[x,y] is Protected`

The other problem is that it gives me also another type of error:

"{NDsolve[{(w1^(0,4))[x,y]+(w1^(2,2))[x,y]+(w1^(4,0))[x,y]==0,{w1[0,y]==0,w1[5,y]==0,((w1^(2,0))[x,y]==0)[0,y]==0,((w1^(2,0))[x,y]==0)[5,y]==0},{w1[x,0]==3,w1[x,5]==3,((w1^(0,2))[x,y]==0)[x,0]==0,((w1^(0,2))[x,y]==0)[x,10]==0}},w1[x,y],{x,0,10},{y,0,5}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Thank you in advance.

---

I made some changes.

First of all I fixed the boundary conditions because they had a problem. 
Moreover I changed also the equation.

Now it still gives me the error:

"{NDsolve[{(w^(0,4))[x,y]+(w^(2,2))[x,y]+(w^(4,0))[x,y]==2,{w[0,y]==0,w[5,y]==0,chix[0,y]==0,chix[5,y]==0},{w[x,0]==0,w[x,10]==0,chiy[x,0]==0,chiy[x,10]==0}},w,{x,0,5},{y,0,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

[image: Click to check the script]

If we succeed in fixing this problem, Mathematica should give us a non zero solution.

Thank you very much!

---

Rewriting it, it doesn't provide any solution. And it also gives no errors. It looks like it is not even substitutiing the boundary conditions. I decided to change them, solving in this way another kind of problem. It still doesn't work. I think that it is very strange, since if the boundary conditions were wrong it should have provided either an indeterminate condition or an impossible one. Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help!

[image: Click here to check the script]

Comment: I edited the post to show what has now changed

Comment: I edited the post, it's very strange... I also made some changes, but it doens't provide any solution. Any idea? Thank you very much!